# What are the object types of the mouse events in Javascript/Angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to create a simple object info tooltip when the user hovers for a few milliseconds on some divs. So, I'm doing a couple of tests to try the mouse event handling in Angular 6. This is what I've got so far in the Angular component:

HTML template:

```
<div (mouseenter)="showObjectInfo($event)"
  (mouseleave)="clearObjectInfo($event)" [attr.data-item]="item.id">
```

Component TS:

```
showObjectInfo(e : any) {
  console.log('<<< ENTER DIV');
  this.infoTooltipTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('TOOLTIP FOR ', e, e.target.getAttribute('data-item'), typeof e);
  }, 1400);
}

clearObjectInfo(e : any) {
  console.log('>>> LEAVE');

  if(this.infoTooltipTimer) {
    clearTimeout(this.infoTooltipTimer);

    this.infoTooltipTimer = undefined;
  }
}
```

So far, it works fine. But I've come across a doubt. I'd like to give the event its correct type (as you can see, right now it's 'any'). I've searched in the W3Schools website and I found that the event type should be 'MouseEvent', like you can see in the following picture:

[image]

However, if I declare the event as `e : MouseEvent`, Typescript complains that 'Property getAttribute does not exist on type EventTarget', in the `showObjectInfo` function.

What is the right object type? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Googling a bit, I found an easy way to get the type of any object in Javascript:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(object)
```

Using it inside my event handler, I got that the event passed to it is of type:

```
[object MouseEvent]
```

As you can see, it's a `MouseEvent` object, so why did I get the error about unknown property `getAttribute` on `e.target`? Using the same method above, I got that `e.target` is not an `EventTarget`, as the error stated, but an `HTMLElement`. Knowing this, all I had to do was a type cast to get a clean compilation:

```
let item = (<HTMLElement>e.target).getAttribute('data-item');
```